# Protractor Test Result variations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am working with protractor in some projects and when i run projects there are some differences in the messages at the end of the successful test run. In one test i have written the tests normally and when the tests run this message comes

[image]

But in the other i have written using Page Objects and there are one test and 4 assertions in it. but when it runs successfully this message comes

[image]

What i want to know is why in the second scenario the assertions are not shown and why its not in green. What is the reason for this difference and is this an issue, if so how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

That's configured in `jasmineNodeOpts` in your protractor-configuration-file. It's the configuration for the default reporter.
The properties you are looking for are:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  silent: false,
  showColors: true
}
```

The values above are the default ones. In your second screen-shot they are inverted.

Take a look at [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter) for another reporter with more options.